# Are there any high school level mathematical methods for collision detection?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons, collision-detection

Currently working towards the IB (International Baccalaureate) diploma in high school and I'm tasked with writing an extended essay on math. I'm super interested in 2D polygon collision detection. However, there are many methods (algorithms) used in collision detection that may or may not involve mathematics past the high school level. So, I'm currently looking for help in deciding on one specific method of detection which will be analyzed in my essay. Any suggestions?

Comment: Computing the time of collision of two circles moving with constant velocities is a nice application of the quadratic formula.

Comment: Come to think of it, the same is true for collisions between a moving point and a moving line segment, where the point and the segment endpoints are all moving with constant velocities. It will also be a nice introduction to barycentric coordinates. This problem is more relevant to your interest of collision detection between polygons; you simply check the vertices of one against the edges of the other and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Barycentric coordinates seem really cool. I'll do more research on the topic and continue to brainstorm ideas.

Comment: Is collision here time dependent, or does it refer to any overlapping state even considered statically? If the method for checking if a point is within a polygon is cheap, a variation on Gaussian Quadrature can be used to see if polygons overlap in a region of interest.